# Can't Create a Conda environment using Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, conda, environment

I am having difficulty with creating a new conda (Anaconda 3, python 3.7) environment using `Pycharm` (edition 2019.2.2.)

I have added the (hopefully) correct Conda.exe file (from `Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe`) as Conda executable, but the installer does not install the first package (`pip-19.2.2`) while creating the Conda environment.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Please edit you question so it contains an error description.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem with the help of Pycharms support team.

If you are also not able to create a conda environment in Pycharm, first try to run:

```
conda update python-libarchive-c
```

in the anaconda command prompt.

If this doesn't work and pycharm is still stuck while making a virtual environment, do the following:

Look into your log: in pycharm go to help -> show log in explorer.

For me PyCharm stumbled upon the following command:

```
C:\Users\\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe create -p C:\Users\\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Project_OpenPNM -y python=3.7
```

Try running this command directly in the anaconda prompt. Subsequently, activate your environment and add the python interpreter created directly as an excisting interpreter in pycharm.